# Laravel9 - selectRaw sum doubling the result error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have 5 tables I want to join

```
Invoices    Coletes   Clients  TagaCars  Incasaris
id 1           1         1         1         1 
               2
               3
```

My query is:

- summing all the child coletes sum where coletes.invoice_id = invoices.id
- selecting the clients name
- selecting the tagacars model

BUT is supposed to sum all the incasaris(which is basically encashment of an invoice), but when I do the sum in query it is doubling the sum for no reason

This is my query:

```
$invoices = Invoice::join('clients','clients.id','=','invoices.client_id')
->join('taga_cars','taga_cars.id','=','invoices.car_id')

->leftJoin('coletes','coletes.invoice_id','=','invoices.id')
->leftjoin('incasaris','invoices.id','=','i_plati_id')
->selectRaw(' 
sum(coletes.totaleuro) as total,
sum(coletes.totaleuro * invoices.i_rate) as totalabsolut,
sum(incasaris.i_totallei) as totalincasat,
clients.name, invoices.*, taga_cars.model')
->groupBy('invoices.id')
->orderBy('invoices.id')
->get();
```

The problem is only with "totalincasat"

[Here you can see in my SQL the amount of i_totallei for one of my invoices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKVDc.png)

[and here is my DD which is showing the doubled amount for no reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbOpg.png)

I want to mention that at the moment each invoice has only one incasaris belonging to each, and also, all incasaris summed combined would not be summed as 2000, it is simply **doubling the result**
Does anyone have any suggestion? Is my first time I got to this "error" and I don't seem to understand how to fix it.

Comment: please create a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ so everyone can help you clearly. How data stored and table design that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Please check **leftjoin** of `invices` with `incasaris`, you are missing `incasaris.i_plati_id` in bellow mentioned line:

```
->leftjoin('incasaris','invoices.id','=','i_plati_id')
```

Instead of above, it must be like

```
->leftjoin('incasaris','invoices.id','=','incasaris.i_plati_id')
```

Comment: Hello friend, I changed that but the problem still pursues, it seems that my query multiplies the input ammount of incasaris with the number of coletes.  For example if my incasaris input in DB is 2500, and my invoice has 3 coletes summing up to the total of 2500, it actually multiplies that to 7500 for some reason.

Comment: best way is to use Laravel relationship.